# c++ global array with size that is given by user

Tags: c++, syntax

I am trying to solve one competitive programming problem using c++ and DFS algorithm.

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> mygraph[n + 1]; // i need this to be global to use in dfs
    bool visited[n + 1] = {};
    ...

    //here I have to pass my vector mygraph, vertex where to start DFS and array of visited);
    dfs(...); 
}

void dfs(int vertex) {
  // depth first search, recursive
  // should use global mygraph and visited arrays or have them as parameters
}
```

My problem is that I cannot make "`mygraph`" global, because it depands on size "`n`". So I do not understand how to pass it to external function `dfs`. If I just pass it as parameter it will be by value and not by refence, thus dfs that is recursive depth-first-search algorithm won't work.

P.S. I am in 8th grade in school. I am studying by videos `DFS` algorithm. I have studied some c++ syntax but I am still new to it and do not know some tricks yet. This is for competitive programming.

I have tried to send `mygraph` and visited as parameters to `dfs` function, but I realised that those are passed by values not by reference.
I tried to mark `mygraph` and visited as "by reference" using "&" symboo, but it turned out that it is prohibited in c++ to pass those "by reference".
I have tried to make them `global`, but I cannot make them of my desired size n, because n comes from `cin`.

Comment: `vector <int> mygraph[n + 1];` -- This is not legal C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime variable.  That should be `std::vector<std::vector<int>> mygraph(n + 1); `.  You make the same error here: `bool visited[n + 1] = {};` -- That should be `std::vector<bool> visited(n+1);`.  The bottom line is to stop using competitive programming sites as learning tools for C++.

Comment: what you miss is not "tricks". Actually you should strive to avoid tricks and write plain simple code.

Comment: You can very well pass a vector by reference, the problem is that you declared an array of  n + 1 vectors instead of a vector with n + 1 members.

Comment: Did you want to declare a single vector that holds `n + 1` elements, or `n + 1` vectors?  Your code, even though not legal, attempted to create `n + 1` vectors.  But this is just another sign that you can't learn C++ by doing competitive programming.  Those competitive programming sites assume you know the computer language you will be using well-enough to *never* ask basic questions about how to use the language.  If you don't know C++ but know some other computer language (python, Java, etc.), then use that language to answer the competitive coding site's questions.

Comment: `std::vector<int> MyGraph;` in main: `MyGraph.resize(n+1);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wanted to declare array that holds n+1 vectors. It was needed to store Graph structure in it.  Why it is not legal? It compiles and even works. https://onlinegdb.com/-_ttvRc6t

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - 1) am I right that I should use vector of vectors instead and then I can pass by reference, right? 2) and if I want to use array of vectors then I should know size in advance and not take it from stdin; even thou my code compiles it is not allowed C++ syntax and the code could not compile in some compilers?

Comment: @Jēkabs 1) [Your code is not legal](https://godbolt.org/z/6zxhc9P8s).  2) You should use `std::vector`, as that is the class that is standard for dynamic arrays.

Comment: [Here is your code, cleaned up by using the `using` clause](https://godbolt.org/z/8qofrWbjj).

Comment: As to why your illegal code compiled, it is because the compiler you were using, `g++`, by default allows the illegal syntax.  If you used the proper compiler switches when using `g++`, in this case `-pedantic-errors`, you will see that the code will no longer compile.  It is a shame that `g++` allows usage of this syntax by default, which does nothing but fool new programmers into believing their code is legal C++ when it isn't legal C++.

Answer (score 0):

There's constraints in each competitive programming questions. Example:

> Each test contains multiple test cases. The first line contains the
> number of test cases t (1≤t≤100). The description of the test cases
> follows.
>
> The first line of each test case contains a single integer n
> (1≤n≤100).
>
> The second line of each test case contains n integers a[1],a[2],…,a[n]
> (1≤a[i]≤10^9).

you can declare your **mygraph** globally based on the maximum of N in cosntraints.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_N = 105; // change it to the maximum of statement constraints + 1
vector<int>mygraph[MAX_N];
bool visited[MAX_N];

void dfs(int vertex);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    dfs(1);
}

void dfs(int vertex)
{
    cout<<vertex<<'\n'; // implement yourself
}
```